# C++ How does one insert to, and read from std::map with struct as value correctly?

Tags: c++, c++builder, stdmap

I have a struct with a constructor containing 3 String parameters.
The goal is to  map integer values as key to instances of said struct (inside TContactTable Class).
The part of code inserting the values compiles, however, when I try to read the value belonging to a key inside TContactTable, I get the error(s):

`Could not find match for 'AttributePackage::AttributePackage()'. Could not find a match for pair<const int, AttributePackage>::pair(const int, undefined)`

(Note: I use C++ Builder, Unicode Strings and TStringList which is a Delphi Container for Strings.)

This is the struct:

```
__fastcall AttributePackage::AttributePackage(String a, String b, String 
c)
{
   a = a;
   b = b;
   c = c;
}
```

Header of Struct:

```
#ifndef TAttributePackageH
#define TAttributePackageH
//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
#include <System.Classes.hpp>

struct AttributePackage
{
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    __fastcall AttributePackage(String a, String b, String c);
};

#endif
```

This is what the map looks like in the header:

`std::map<int, AttributePackage> attributeMap;`

This is how I create the objects and insert them into the map:

```
__fastcall TContactTable::TContactTable()
{
    AttributePackage pkgValues1("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
    AttributePackage pkgValues2("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");

    AttributePackage attrPkgs[2] = {pkgValues1,pkgValues2};

    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        attributeMap[i] = attrPkgs[i];
}
```

This is how I read the objects:

```
TStringList* __fastcall TContactTable:getAttributeCaptions()
{
    TStringList *list = new TStringList;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)  
        String a = attributeMap[i].a; // this line throws said errors.
        //list->Add(a); //what I intend to do later
    return list;
}
```

The intent is to read the attributes "a" of the struct at position i of the map and return them in a list of strings to a different class.
I'm wondering if it has to do with the way the struct objects have been created without new.
I'm obviously new to c++ and would be thankful for any advice.

UPDATE:

I changed 2 things which resolved the issue.

1. the constructor of the struct had the issue of the parameters having the same name as the class variables. so a = a assigned empty values to itself.
2. The struct needed a default constructor since the operator[]
   requires a class to be default constructible.

Thank you @vll for helping me along the way.

Comment: What is `AttributePackage`? What is `structName::structName()`? They are not not in the code you posted.

Comment: Where is the definition of `i` in `getAttributeCaptions()`? Are you sure it is a number?

Comment: @vll I tried to simplify it but made it more confusing and left out some critical parts. structName should be Attribute Package. I added the struct as I defined it and I added the loop containing index i.

Comment: `operator[]` requires that the class is default constructible. Add a default constructor or use `at(i)` instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: I added the default constructor to the struct. The code compiles now but when I log the strings they show up as empty strings.

Comment: It was because i had a = a in the constructor of the struct. I changed the name of the argument String a_, String b_ and so forth and it worked then.

Answer (score 1):

[`map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) tries to insert a **default**-constructed object into the `map` if the requested key does not exist.  But your struct does not have a default constructor, hence the compiler errors.

So, the simplest solution is to add a default constructor to your struct.  But, if that is not an option, then you will have to use [`map::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) to add new entries into your `map`, and use [`map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) to search for existing keys, eg:

```
std::map<int, AttributePackage> attributeMap;

__fastcall TContactTable::TContactTable()
{
    AttributePackage pkgValues1("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
    AttributePackage pkgValues2("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");

    AttributePackage& attrPkgs[2] = {pkgValues1, pkgValues2};

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        attributeMap.insert(std::make_pair(i, attrPkgs[i]));
}

TStringList* __fastcall TContactTable:getAttributeCaptions()
{
    TStringList *list = new TStringList;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        auto iter = attributeMap.find(i);
        if (iter != attributeMap.end())
        {
            String a = iter->a;
            list->Add(a);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

That being said, you are using indexes for the `map` keys.  For that, I would suggest using a `std::vector` instead of a `std::map`, eg:

```
std::vector<AttributePackage> attributeVec;

__fastcall TContactTable::TContactTable()
{
    AttributePackage pkgValues1("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
    AttributePackage pkgValues2("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");

    AttributePackage& attrPkgs[2] = {pkgValues1, pkgValues2};

    attributeVec.reserve(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        attributeVec.push_back(attrPkgs[i]);

    /* alternatively:
    attributeVec.reserve(2);
    attributeVec.emplace_back("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
    attributeVec.emplace_back("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
    */
}

TStringList* __fastcall TContactTable:getAttributeCaptions()
{
    TStringList *list = new TStringList;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < attributeVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        String a = attributeVec[i].a;
        list->Add(a);
    }

    /* alternatively:
    for(auto &elem : attributeVec)
    {
        String a = elem.a;
        list->Add(a);
    }
    */

    return list;
}
```